# How to convert array to string in forloop()?

Tags: php, arrays, string, for-loop

Hey I have this piece of code here:

```
 <?php for($t=1; $t<=4;$t++ ){ 
<input name="total_hours" type="hidden" value="<?=$totalhoursweek.$t['Duration'];?>">
<?php };?>
```

How can I dynamically use the variable `$t`?

Result expected:

```
$totalhoursweek1['Duration'];
$totalhoursweek2['Duration'];
$totalhoursweek3['Duration'];
$totalhoursweek4['Duration'];
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Also, almost any time you seem to need to use variable variables, there are probably some things in your code you need to rethink.

Comment: Creating one variable like `$totalhoursweek[1]['Duration']`, etc. instead of four separate variables would be better, if you could do something like that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: well, that's just the way it is for now... I'm only doing this one time... It's probably bad practice but I can't go over the code as of today

Comment: Sure, no offense intended. Just offering my unsolicited opinion. :)